# ACAccountStore no longer work with Twitter? (Swift, iOS 12)

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-oauth, acaccountstore

I have a method that allows user to follow other twitter account using twitter API, however, this method stopped working since `iOS 11`.

Because:
Social accounts have been removed from Settings in iOS 11. Third-party apps no longer have access to those signed-in accounts. (31687059)

(In the following method, the return value "isGranted" will be false, and error code will be: error 7, from apple.com)

Is there a way to work around this?

```
static func followAppTwitter(_ twitterScreenName: String) {

    let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
    let twitterType = accountStore.accountType(withAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

    accountStore.requestAccessToAccounts(with: twitterType, options: nil,
        completion: { (isGranted, error) in
            guard let userAccounts = accountStore.accounts(with: twitterType),
                userAccounts.count > 0 else { return }
            guard let firstActiveTwitterAccount = userAccounts[0] as? ACAccount else { return }

            // Then do a data post to twitter API
            // ......
    })
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to find a good substitute.. did you end up with a decent solution?

Comment: @MichaelRowe ahhh I didn't. let me know if you found one.

Comment: @MichaelRowe did you find the solution yet?

Comment: I switched over to SwifteriOS  seems to be working fine for me... I store the credentials in my app space now...

Answer (score 1):

After searching around for a while - I have replaced my code with - https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter SwifterIOS

Comment: Anything similar or equivalent for Objective-C? 

Comment: I’ve not looked at objective c for a while.